# Why socket.io is messing up my ajax headers?

Tags: javascript, ajax, socket.io, xmlhttprequest, laravel-echo

I am using custom headers in ajax requests:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function (xhr)
                {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",  'Bearer ' + token);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept",  'application/json');
                }
            });
```

It was working great until I added socket.io chat to my app. When I include socket.io.js file served by my socket.io server my headers are gone :(

Sure I can put my headers in every ajax request but it's not convenient. My original approach is cleaner.

Anyone can help me with this? Why my headers are gone? Is there a way to make them work again while using socket.io?

**UPDATE**

When I get rid of socket.io.js script include:

```
<script src="http://localhost:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

It's all working fine. And no, there are no errors because I do it this way:

```
if(typeof io !== 'undefined') {
    self.echo = window.Echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'socket.io',
        host: CONFIG.socket_url + ":" + CONFIG.socket_port,
        auth: {
               headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth.getToken(),
                        Accept:  'application/json'
               },
        },
     });
 }
```

**UPDATE2**

Well the problem might be not the socket.io, but laravel-echo (which uses socket.io for broadcasting).

Comment: I find it kind of hard to believe those two things are related.  The socket.io client has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery as far as I know so it seems kind of hard to believe that it messes with jQuery ajax calls by removing custom headers.  It seems more likely that you've introduced some other problem at the same time.

Comment: Well it was hard to believe it for me, but when I comment out the line where I load the script (<script src="http://localhost:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>) it's all working fine (besides socket.io of course)

Comment: Well, commenting out only that line, likely causes errors elsewhere in your script with the code that attempted to initialize and use that socket.io connection which can change the course of other code.  We can really only help you if we can see the WHOLE problem, not just four lines of code.  You're basically asking us to make blind and wild guesses that you will then comment on.  That's not a very productive way for us to help solve the problem.

Comment: I will reply in my post update.

Comment: FYI, this `<script src="localhost:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` is not a valid URL.  It should be `<script src="http://localhost:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`.  You need a protocol.

Comment: @jfriend00 it's gonna be hard to post WHOLE code, which is hundreds of files.

Comment: What is `new Echo()`?

Comment: @jfriend00 http:// was cut somehow when I posted my comment

Comment: @jfriend00 hmmm, probably You just helped me :) Echo is client side lib for laravel-echo server. Maybe it's messing up my headers. I will check it and let you know.

Comment: No, still don't have an idea why it's happening. I don't see anything in Echo source which can override the headers :(

Comment: What if you comment out that Echo code?  Look, all I can do is comment on code I can see.  I stand by my assertion that there's nothing in socket.io that messes with jQuery Ajax calls.  So, the problem is probably caused by code you are running when socket.io is active, not by socket.io itself.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yup, you're right. It's not the socket.io. It's laravel-echo issue. Thanks. It still doesn't solve my problem, but now I have new area to search for the solution  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you comment out that Echo code?

Look, all I can do is comment on code I can see. I stand by my assertion that there's nothing in socket.io that messes with jQuery Ajax calls.

So, the problem is probably caused by code you are running when socket.io is active, not by socket.io itself.